# How do I check if a point is within a rotated ellipsoid?

Tags: geometry

I know that I can check whether a point is within an ellipsoid with this equation:

```
(x/a)^2 + (y/b)^2 + (z/c)^2 = 1
```

and for the case that the ellipsoid is not centered in the origin but in the point (xc, yc, zc) it changes to

```
((x-xc)/a)^2 + ((y-yc)/b)^2 + ((z-zc)/c)^2 = 1
```

However, I had to additionally rotate my elliipsoid either around the x-axis or around the y-axis and I can not figure out how to adjust this equation for this case.

Any help would be great.

Cheers, 
Peter

Answer (score 1):

If rotation is known, the simplest way is to apply back rotation to the point and check whether it lies inside axis-aligned ellipsoid.

For example, if ellipsoid is rotated around x-axis by angle `Fi` around some axis and then shifted by `(xc, yc, zc)`, you can shift point by `(-xc, -yc, -zc)` and rotate by `-Fi` around the same axis, then check the simplest

```
(x/a)^2 + (y/b)^2 + (z/c)^2 <= 1
```